# EventHandler not firing on resize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, eventhandler

I have created an event like this:

```
Private Handler1 As New EventHandler(AddressOf resize_page)
```

Then in my sub I add it like this:

```
  AddHandler Main.Resize, Handler1
```

Then I have a Sub which handles it

```
Private Sub resize_page(){
 ' do something
}
```

My subroutine never gets called when I resize my form. The actions in it never get performed. I even put a MessageBox in it as the first line and my message never pops up so I know it is not being called.

Why is it not firing?

Comment: where/when/how do you RaiseEvent??  Forms come with their own resize event anyway - no need for custom ones.

Comment: `AddHandler Me.Resize, Handler1`.  Your `resize_page` method looks very c#-ish.  Consider just overriding the OnResize method instead.

Comment: You can just call AddHander Me.Resize, AddressOf resize_page

Comment: Sorry, the braces on the Sub do not belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a weird combination of events which I still can't explain or figure out, but I finally got to the bottom of it by removing everything and tracing it backwards.

I have several modules in this app and each module opens up a panel that takes up the whole width and height of the form (there is only one form), so it is like a "page". When the user is done with the page, he hits a close button which disposes of everything in that module. So he is effectively closing the page and going to another one. Since each page takes up the whole width and height of the form, I want it to expand to fill the form whenever the form size changes. So every module has an event listener which listens for the "Main" form to resize.

This is what happened:

I created a listener on page one so it could resize itself (which worked fine)

I created a listener on page two so it could resize itself, but I accidentally had a call to the listener for page one on this page. So it had two listeners, which didn't throw an error because the resize sub for page one was mistakenly made public instead of private.

The event listener for page 3 was the one that wasn't working although it was created just like the one for page one.

After tracing it backwards, I discovered the listener on page 2 that was calling the sub on page 1 and removed it. Once I removed it, the listener on page 3 started working like it should. I still can't figure out why because even though page one gets disposed of it elements, its resize sub, which was public, should still be accessible from page 2. When the page gets disposed I remove the event listeners along with everything else. However there was a link on page 2 which opened page 3 without page 2 being disposed and this somehow prevented page 3's listener from being fired.

Anyway, it was as simple as that and now it works as expected so I'll move on.

Thanks for the info.

Comment: +1. Thank you for sharing your solution. Please don't forget to accept an answer to let other members know the problem has been resolved and does not require more attention.

Answer (score 0):

What is Main referring to?

You are adding the handler to the wrong thing is my guess.
You want to add the handler to your form so either.

```
AddHandler Me.Resize, Handler1
```

or maybe

```
 AddHandler [Yourforminstance].Resize, Handler1
```

Also you seem to have languages mixed up? or is it just me? lol

should be

```
    Private Sub resize_page()
      'Code here
    End Sub
```